# How can I change displayed name as sender?

Tags: 14.04, email, mail-server

I send email from my server like this:

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" user@example.com
```

Noted that I replace `user@example.com` with a real email address. And it works. Just I need to know, where this nickname comes from?

[image]

I use ubuntu 14.04 on the server and I want to know how can I change that name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use `mail`, there are better command-line MUAs, such as `mailx` (package `bsd-mailx`) or `mutt`.

`mailx` will do what you want with the `-r` flag:

```
echo Test. | mailx -r "Joe Sender <sender@domain.com>" -s Test recipient@domain.com
```

You can likewise specify a display name for the recipient, by the way.

The nickname shown in for instance gmail.com comes from the part of the `From` field that is outside `<sender@domain.com>`, so in this example it would be Joe Sender.

Comment: Great .. thank you .. upvote. Just in reality my problem is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988938/how-can-i-assign-an-user-as-owner-of-a-script). if you have some free time, please take a look at it.

Comment: This does not work. When I send an email to my google mail account, it only shows the address `sender@domain.com` but not the "Joe Sender"...

Answer (score 3):

Using `mail`, you can set the username using the proper syntax, such as `echo "Test" | mail -a "From: Someone <someone@example.com>" other@example.com`.

Comment: Thanks! This is the only solution that works from all mentioned solutions...