# How can I assign an user as owner of a script?

Tags: 14.04, php, email

Here is my command:

```
echo "This is the body of the email" | mail -s "This is the subject line" myemail@address.com
```

When I ran this command with `root` user, that email goes into *inbox* and all file. But sadly  when I switch to another user (`su info`) and then send that email with another user, it goes into *spam*.

---

Noted that `info` has `sudo` priviliges. In reality I need to send that email using a PHP script like this:

```
// send_email.php
<?php
    $msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";
    $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);
    mail("myemail@address.com","My subject",$msg);
?>
```

When I execute that php script, that email sends as well, but the sad part is, the sender name will be shown as `www-date@lamtakam.com`. As you know `www-date` is apache's user which executes that script.

So all I'm trying to do is putting user `info` as the owner of that script. **My goal is making sender like `info@lamtakam.com`.**

Any idea how can do that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890134/php-mail-how-to-set-sender-mail - in short: you are barking up the wrong tree. Don't bother about the user running it; simply **set** the envelope sender address.

Comment: And as a side note: This is an [classical X-Y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It's always better to ask about your real problem, and not what you perceive the solution to be.